# XMLHttpRequest in Firefox on websites meta information

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon

I am new to Firexfox Add-On development and I would like to parse meta-tags from a website in the internet. My Firefox Add-On development environment is setup completely and a panel in the toolbar appears as it should be. When I open the panel the current visited website should be read by its meta-tags. In the following you will see amazon.de as example.

This is how my main.js file looks like:

```
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var self = require("sdk/self");

var button = ToggleButton({
  id: "my-button",
  label: "my button",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onChange: handleChange
});

var panel = panels.Panel({
  contentURL: self.data.url("panel.html"),
  onHide: handleHide
});

function handleChange(state) {
  if (state.checked) {
    panel.show({
      position: button
    });
  }
}

function handleHide() {
  button.state('window', {checked: false});
}
```

And this is the panel where the current visited website should be read by its meta-tags:

```
<script>
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.open("GET", "http://www.amazon.de/Apple-Smartphone-Retina-Display-Megapixel-Bluetooth/dp/B00F8JF2OM/", false); 
    req.send(null);

    var xmlDoc = req.responseXML;       

    var nsResolver = xmlDoc.createNSResolver( xmlDoc.ownerDocument == null ? xmlDoc.documentElement : xmlDoc.ownerDocument.documentElement);

    //XPath 'html//meta[@name="title"]/@content'
    var itemIterator = xmlDoc.evaluate('html//meta[@name="title"]/@content', xmlDoc, nsResolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );

    var thisHeading = itemIterator.iterateNext();

    var alertText = 'Items:\n'

    while (thisHeading) {
      alertText += thisHeading.textContent + '\n';
      thisHeading = itemIterator.iterateNext();
    }
</script>
```

I don't get any errors and don't get any alert or output data.
However the Firfox XPath add-on tells me the path is correct and shows the data.

Comment: if the site is already loaded in the current tab how come you are doing a xhr request to it again?

Comment: ...because i do not know how to get the current loaded website on another way.

Comment: try the tab module. you can get the activeTab. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs `tabs.activeTab` can even go `tabs.activeTab.window.contentWindow` try that